# How do I open a new window using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following two ways suggested to me.

```
window.location.href = '/Administration/Notes/Create?dsValue=a&selectAnswer=b';
$.get("/Administration/Notes/Create", { dsValue: dsValue, selectedAnswer: answer });
```

Are these methods the same? Which one would be the best for me to use and what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are by no means the same. The first will simply send you to whatever URL you have assigned to window.location.href (in the same window you're currently in).  The second makes a GET AJAX request.

Try this page: http://www.codebelt.com/jquery/open-new-browser-window-with-jquery-custom-size/

It gives a great example on how to open a new window*.

If you wish to use raw javascript then this is what you're looking for:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

As seen in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: w3schools is my least favorite reference.  Much better information at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open.

Comment: Nice. Never actually looked at _their_ docs. I guess I use w3schools out of old habits. I bookmarked that page thanks!

Comment: People are freaking haters... Microsoft, Apple, w3schools, get off it already!

Comment: The reason people end up hating on w3schools is because many times there is out-right bad advice. I do believe most if not all of this has been cleaned up. However It's hard to change first impressions. MDN is a fantastic place for information. You can also look at this project: https://www.webplatform.org/ however I'm not sure how active the community is.

Answer (score 16):

It's not really something you need jQuery to do. There is a very simple plain old javascript method for doing this:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','GoogleWindow', 'width=800, height=600');
```

That's it.

The first arg is the url, the second is the name of the window, this should be specified because IE will throw a fit about trying to use `window.opener` later if there was no window name specified (just a little FYI), and the last two params are width/height.

EDIT:
Full specification can be found in the link mmmshuddup provided.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
myWindow = window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','myWindow', "width=200, height=200");
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: What link are you talking about?