# Is there any possibility to open a anchor tag in new window with writing javascript code or JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually i am trying to write anchor tag with href to open in new window not in new tab
as i read in somewhere  target="_blank" opens in new tab or new window so i tried like below

```
 <a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank">gmail</a>
```

but its opened in new tab not in new window.

Now I need to open in new window with writing javascript and JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075948/how-do-i-open-a-new-window-using-jquery

Comment: Pelase specify the browser. Have you tried changing the settings.

Comment: I am using Google chrome  and Firefox latest browsers

Comment: I red the above link but here i am not using javascirt or JQuery

Comment: window.open() should do the trick .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a new tab or window when a link is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470075/how-can-i-open-a-new-tab-or-window-when-a-link-is-clicked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why go for JavaScript or jquery, just do it like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/','mywindow','width=1100,height=500');">Open google in new window</a>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qDN5j/2/)

Comment: This is also Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

do

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var windowName = $(this).attr('id');
    window.open(url, windowName, "height=500,width=500");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
 <a href="#"  onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','new window',config='height=900, width=1200, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no')">Click Here</a>
```